# How do I get ServiceStack to work in an MVC4 project?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I created a new MVC 4 Project, and updated it from NuGet with all required ServiceStack packages.

I added this to my `Web.config`:

```xml
<location path="ss">
  <system.web>
    <!-- httpHandlers added for ServiceStack, this will work for IIS6 and Below -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ServiceStack.Factory" path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

My `AppHost`:

```cs
namespace MySql_Test.App_Start
{
    public class ApplicationHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public ApplicationHost()
            : base("PersonService", typeof(PersonService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "ss" });

            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DuDealsConnStr"].ConnectionString,
                    ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql.MySqlDialectProvider.Instance));
        }
    }

    public class PersonService : Service
    {
    }
}
```

My `Global.cs`:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        (new ApplicationHost()).Init();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

When I build and run the project and try to navigate to `localhost/ss/metadata`
it just keeps giving me a 404 page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default MVC4 project uses WebApi by default. You need to prevent WebApi from registering to receive the requests that you want ServiceStack to handle.

See the ServiceStack documentation, [Create your first webservice](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice#disable-webapi-from-the-default-mvc4-vsnet-template) instructions:

> **Disable WebApi from the default MVC4 VS.NET template**
>   If you are using MVC4 then you need to comment line in global.asax.cs to disable WebApi

```cs
//WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

So set your `Application_Start` to simply be:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    (new ApplicationHost()).Init();
}
```

---

If you want ServiceStack to work alongside WebApi then you will need to tell WebApi to not handle requests starting with your `ss/` path:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    (new ApplicationHost()).Init();

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Ignore ServiceStack routes
    RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("ss/{*pathInfo}");

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, the only thing missing in my code was the IgnoreRoute("ss..."); There was no conflict with the webapi as those url begin with api/ 

That Piece of information is confusing in the ServiceStack documentation :) https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework as they keep talking about the webapi. As per my understanding SS can be hosted under any url, so I chose ss to work along with WebApi.